Static variables in functions that are called frequently
void storeValidVIDS()
{
    static unsigned int mainVID = 0, maxVID = 0, minVID = 0;
    static unsigned long* currentInstance = nullptr;
    mainVID = GetMainActorVID();
    maxVID = mainVID + 5000;
    minVID = mainVID - 5000;
    while (minVID < maxVID)
    {
        currentInstance = GetInstancePTR(minVID);
        if (HasInstance(currentInstance) && GetInstanceType(currentInstance) == 6)
            validVids.insert(minVID);
        ++minVID;
    }
}

using this function as an example which loops over a range of virtual ids and stores them in an unordered_set if the condition is true.
assuming this function is called continuously each 100 milliseconds, is it better performance wise to use static variables since they are initialized once?
if yes, does it also apply to containers? Can I do something like static std::vector<unsigned int> validTargets = {}; knowing that the function will be called over and over.

What benefit are you expecting from static? I would assume static might be slower because of the thread-safe static initialization rule.

Questions about performance should typically include some benchmark showing the effect of using some idiom/feature over another. For a language like C++ with aggressively optimizing compilers, trying to guess the performance impact of a snippet of code is futile, and likely pointless.

If anything static is going to make this code slower. Don't get hung up on micro-optimizations. But if you must then only you and your compiler can answer which is faster. There is no general rule like 'Use static variables to make your code go faster'. Everything is contingent.

Why you need this variables to be static at all? All of them are overridden in each function call or before been read. Just drop this static keyword and behavior of this function will not change and it will be faster.

As soon as you are anywhere close to an std::unordered_set, worrying about micro-performance is really pointless. It's like flying in a plane and wondering if clipping your nails before you board will make you arrive faster because the plane is lighter.

Since you don't use the "retained" values of these variables and they are primitives, static is pure overhead, both through the thread-safe initialization check and the need to store them somewhere in RAM.

Considering that you do have to initialize the variables only once and that you have to do that on every call:
int mainVID = GetMainActorVID();
int maxVID = mainVID + 5000;
int minVID = mainVID - 5000;

There is, frankly, no value in pondering about whether initializing them only once would gain performance.

static is not a magic keyword to make functions run faster. You use static when you need a variable to persist during function calls. For example:
unsigned increment() {
     static unsigned value = 0;
     return ++value;
}

The function returns a value that increases by 1 on each call.

Really nobody can reliably tell you what the compiler does to the code but the compiler. You have to measure and profile to know what is more performant.
Nevertheless, there is no reason to expect your version with the static variables to run significantly faster. And because since C++11 initialization of function local static variables is thread safe, you can actually expect it to be slower with static rather than without.
(Note however that it is only initialization. In the above example this would mean that of two or more threads concurrently calling increment only one will initialize value. Though after that reading and writing is not automatically synchronized.)

Last but not least, 100 ms is a long time on a typical CPU. If the function takes considerably less than 100 ms then there is no need to make it any faster. You are in the fortunate situation to know exactly how fast you need to be. Attach a profiler to measure how long the execution of the function in your real code takes. If it takes less then 100 ms you are fine. Only if it takes more you have to do something about it.

Don't.

static initialization has higher overhead, due to thread safety guarantees.
Initialization of a local primitive is negligible compared to insert into an unordered map.
Making them non-static, any decent optimizer will remove the extra assignment.

Moreover: it changes semantics. It makes your code look "surprising", and that makes people want to rewrite instead of building on it.
